# lenovo ideapad s510g laptop screen display not able to see anything

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, led

I have a Lenovo Laptop S510g, the issue is a black screen.

if I connect to TV by using HDMI Cable I can see that monitor is displayed correctly, and also I tried turning on torch so I can see the monitor.

I don't know what's the issue.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 0):

just for the guys who is looking to fix this.

Tried some simple steps for LENOVO S510P SERIES.

1. removed battery
2. pressed power button for 10-15 sec
3. connected battery charger
4. pressed power button untill the Beep Sound
5. got restarted
6. shutdown
7. inserted battery again
8. unplugged battery charger
9. left for 10min
10. switched on Laptop
11. Done !!